# Inflate textviews with differents values in a Layout

Tags: java, android

I already looked for some answer on the internet but i didn't find so i'm asking for your help
I want to add a TextView everytime i click on a button but with a different value.
For exemple, first click adds a TextView with the number 1, second click adds a TextView with the number 2.
My app crashs everytime i call the method.

Here the code

```
public class Activity_Planification_Actu extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout mparent;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.page_planification);
        mparent = findViewById(R.id.Layout1);
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }



    public void boutonTest(View v) {

        View myview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.semaine_planif, null, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.case_semaine);
        tv.setText(i);
        i++;
        mparent.addView(myview);

    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_entete_accueil"
        layout="@layout/tabdebut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="1647dp"
        android:layout_height="930dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/include_entete_accueil"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="82dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="94dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="69dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="87dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="84dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="81dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="63dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="82dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boutontest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:onClick="boutonTest"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include_entete_accueil" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
06-17 17:25:10.766 6841-6841/com.imsnancydaunot.imscoaching E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.imsnancydaunot.imscoaching, PID: 6841
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4417)
        at categ_planification.Activity_Planification_Actu.boutonTest(Activity_Planification_Actu.java:34)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/02iKs.png

To be more precised i want right to the textview another textview but with a different text

Comment: Please show your layouts and crash stack-trace

Comment: Hi thank you for answering, i edited with the layouts and logcats

Comment: where is your button code

Comment: the button code is in the layout that contains onClick method

Comment: Issue is in semaine_planif layout. Post that too

Comment: Hi Brendon,
I added the layout

Comment: @fcandrofans I found problem please see my answer

Comment: Try setting text view with i.toString() text view won't support integer directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in:

```
tv.setText(i);
```

You call to setText with `int` argument and Android think that you pass String's resource id like `tv.setText(R.string.some_text)` and
cant find resource which id is equals to `i` i.e. `0` that's why this crash happend .

You should use:

```
tv.setText(String.valueOf(i)); 
//or
tv.setText("" + i);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was the problem here
The code is working as i want

Comment: @fcandrofans Thanks. Please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Thank you again for the time you gave me to resolve my problem, you're a part of a great community !

Answer (score 0):

provide Logcat

or

try this
can do with loop

```
LinearLayout my_ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout1);
        for(int i=0;i<your_number_of_textviews;i++)
        {
            TextView text = new TextView(this);
            text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            text.setText("text"+i);
            my_ll.addView(text);
        }
```

every button click logic

```
LinearLayout my_ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout1);
int clickcount=0; //set as global 
yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickcount=clickcount+1;
        if(clickcount==0)
        {
            //check how many times clicked and so on
            //here, you can add textview without loop 
            TextView text = new TextView(this);
            text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            text.setText("text"+clickcount);
            my_ll.addView(text);

        
    }
});
```

Comment: i added a picture to show you what i wanted